# Are there any algorithms for simultaneous optimization of multiple objective functions?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I would like to minimize a set of similar objective functions

$$f_\boldsymbol{s}(\boldsymbol{x}),$$

where $\boldsymbol{x} \in A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^M$ and the parameterization $\boldsymbol{s} \in S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^N$ distinguishes the objective functions that I want to minimize.

edit1: I assume $f_\boldsymbol{s}(\boldsymbol{x})$ to be continuous in $\boldsymbol{s}$.

The solution that I am looking for is a model $\hat{g}$ of $g: S \rightarrow A$ so that
$$\forall \boldsymbol{s} \in S, \forall \boldsymbol{x} \in A: f_\boldsymbol{s}(g(\boldsymbol{s})) \leq f_\boldsymbol{s}(\boldsymbol{x}).$$

In other words, I try to solve the problem

$$\hat{g} = \arg \min_{g} \int_{\boldsymbol{s} \in S} f_{\boldsymbol{s}}(g(\boldsymbol{s}))d\boldsymbol{s}$$

- Is this kind of problem known in the optimization community?
- Are there any algorithms that are able to solve these kind of problems?

**I am not looking for multi-objective optimizers!**

Comment: unless you assume that $f$ is a nice function of two variables, or at least continuous in $s$, I guess it's like solving several unrelated problems. For example, if $f\in C^1$ as a function of $s,x$, then $g(s)$ must parametrize the level set $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 0$

Comment: I find your "in other words" formulation rather confusing. I guess you're just defining $g(s)=\arg\min_x f_s(x)$, which amounts to solving a different optimization problem for each $s$.

Comment: @Ilya: Yes, that is my assumption. $f_s(x)$ should be contiuous in $s$.

Comment: @Rahul: Because of this assumption, we can "share knowledge" about the optimum between different elements of $S$.

Comment: If the true minimum $g(\boldsymbol{s}) \in A$ was e.g. quadratic, we would require less function evaluations to find a quadratic model $\hat{g}(\boldsymbol{s})$ than we would require to minimize $f$ for each element of $S$ separately.

Comment: I just remembered that I asked [a similar question](http://mathoverflow.net/q/30143) on MathOverflow a few years ago. If you take $g$ to be set-valued (in case there are multiple global minima), you get what one might call the *argmin correspondence*. Only the term *argmax correspondence* seems to appear in the literature, though. See the comments in my link for why $g$ can be pretty nasty even if $f$ is well-behaved.

Comment: At a first sight I think this is related. Thank you!